# How to securize Struts2 Rest services with Spring Security Oauth

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, struts2, oauth-2.0

I struggle with configuration of spring security Oauth to use it on a Struts2 Application to secure rest webservices.
I already use spring security for a long time.

The issue, if I have well understantood, is that Spring security Oauth need spring mvc dispatcher set on root. And this is conflicting with Struts2.

Here are my attempts

2) Struts2 on root and Spring MVC on /oauth/*

```
<!-- Struts 2 -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/struts/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

<servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

This is OK for Oauth but Struts2 doesn't work anymore.

1) Struts2 and Spring MVC on root

```
<!-- Struts 2 -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/struts/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

<servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/oauth/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Struts2, oauth is recognizing rights but the response is made on /token instead of /oauth/token and so I get a 404 error.

The extract of spring-security.xml is here:

```
<http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"
        authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
        <anonymous enabled="false" />
        <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
        <!-- include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request 
            parameters -->
        <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />

</http>

<!-- This is where we tells spring security what URL should be protected 
    and what roles have access to them -->
<http pattern="/api/**.api" create-session="never"
    entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/api/**.api" access="ROLE_API" />
    <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>
```

Comment: Ryder, if you have found the Answer, please post it for others. They are asking for it and getting their answers deleted. Thanks. Of course, you haven't logged in in over a month, so no one hold your breath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use 2 different Spring Dispatchers :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/oauth/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>rest-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>rest-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/restapi/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

One for the Rest WS and the other for securization.

Afterward you will bet the token not on /oauth/token but on /oauth/oauth/token

To solve this problem you have to duplication Spring Security Parameterization :

```
<http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"
    authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
    <!-- include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request 
        parameters -->
    <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>

<http pattern="/oauth/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"
    authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
    <!-- include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request 
        parameters -->
    <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>
```